# Creating PL/SQL function from query

Tags: html, sql, oracle, function, plsql

Little knowledge of PL/SQL here, so need a bit of help.

I have the a query that I need to turn into a function (let's call it reject_list), but not sure how to do it. This is what I have so far:

```
create or replace function reject_list(ayrc in varchar2,mcrc in varchar2)
return string
begin
select distinct
'<tr><td>'||cap.cap_uci2||'</td>
<td>'||cap.cap_stuc||'</td>
<td>'||cap.cap_mcrc||'</td>
<td>'||cap.cap_ayrc||'</td>
<td>'||stu.stu_fnm1||'</td>
<td>'||stu.stu_surn||'</td>
<td>'||cap.cap_stac||'</td>
<td>'||cap.cap_crtd||'</td></tr>'
from
intuit.srs_cap cap
,intuit.ins_stu stu
,intuit.srs_apf apf
where
cap.cap_stuc = stu.stu_code
and cap.cap_apfs = apf.apf_seqn
and cap.cap_stuc = apf.apf_stuc
and cap.cap_mcrc = &mcrc
and cap.cap_ayrc = &ayrc
and cap.cap_idrc in ('R','CR','CFR')
and apf.apf_recd <= to_date('1501'||substr(&ayrc,1,4),'DDMMYYYY');
end;
```

This doesn't run - can anyone help?

Thanks :)

**EDIT:** This query is one that is being run in an application already but we are trying to optimize it for speed. I am not certain whether a function is the best option, but we have, in another part of the application created a function to return simple counts which improved the speed exponentially. I need guidance more than just straightforward instructions on how to turn this into a function. If a view is the best option, for example, please could someone offer some guidance on how would be the best way to do this?

The object, therefore, is to be able to have a query stored on the server which allows me to enter the parameters and return the fields listed. To make this more complicated, one thing I did not mention before is that this needs to be formatted as an HTML table. I have now added the markup that would do this into the query above, and all the fields need to be concatenated.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want to return a cursor, no?

Comment: There's a lot about your question that's unclear.  What do you want your function to return?  (`string` isn't a valid SQL type, in Oracle at least.)  Why do you need to turn your query into a function?  (If it's just to be able to use the same query in multiple places without repeating it, you might be better off with a view.)  In SQL Server, stored functions can return the result of a SELECT query - are you looking for the Oracle equivalent of this?

Comment: Please see the edits I have made above. I initially put this up in a bit of a rush, hence the lack of information, but please let me know if anything else needs clarification.

Comment: @LukeWoodward - STRING is perfectly valid in Oracle.  It's defined in SYS.STANDARD as `subtype STRING is VARCHAR2;`.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Further questions: when you say "doesn't run", what do you mean?  Do you get an error, and if so, what?  Why do you need `SELECT DISTINCT` in your query?  What indexes are on the tables?  Roughly how many rows are in the tables and roughly how many rows should the query return?  How is this function being called, and from what language?  Also, why do you need to return HTML from the database?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the execution plan for this query.  Also, knowing what indexes exist on these tables would be a big help.  Thanks.

Comment: @LukeWoodward - if I recall correctly STRING is an ANSI datatype so Oracle has to support it to be able to say they're ANSI-compliant.  I've read a lot of Oracle code over the years and don't recall seeing STRING used anywhere.  Just another feature-list item, kind of like INTEGER (also in SYS.STANDARD - `subtype INTEGER is NUMBER(38,0)`) and FLOAT (yep, in there too - `subtype FLOAT is NUMBER`, which is kind of funny), and a pile of other types.  SYS.STANDARD's really an interesting package to read through (yes, I need to get out more - why do you bring that up? :-).  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to loop through the results of the select statement using a cursor.  Please consider the following code as a guide.  http://www.plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-cursors.htm.  Also please consider prefixing your function parameters with P_ or something like that.  It will make them easier to spot in the code.

```
FUNCTION YOUR_FUNCTION(p_ayrc in varchar2,p_mcrc in varchar2) 
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
  IS
    THE_RESULT SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
            OPEN THE_RESULT FOR
              select distinct
        cap.cap_uci2
        ,cap.cap_stuc
        ,cap.cap_mcrc
        ,cap.cap_ayrc
        ,stu.stu_fnm1
        ,stu.stu_surn
        ,cap.cap_stac
        ,cap.cap_crtd
        from
        intuit.srs_cap cap
        ,intuit.ins_stu stu
        ,intuit.srs_apf apf
        where
        cap.cap_stuc = stu.stu_code
        and cap.cap_apfs = apf.apf_seqn
        and cap.cap_stuc = apf.apf_stuc
        and cap.cap_mcrc = p_mcrc
        and cap.cap_ayrc = p_ayrc
        and cap.cap_idrc in ('R','CR','CFR')
        and apf.apf_recd <= to_date('1501'||substr(&ayrc,1,4),'DDMMYYYY');
            RETURN THE_RESULT;
END;
```

Comment: OK, I think I understand the concept of cursors now, but not really sure how to implement them and this statement still doesn't run. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (you must only change `varchar(256)` on your column's types):

```
create type t_row as object
(
cap_uci2 varchar(256)
, cap.cap_stuc varchar(256)
, cap.cap_mcrc varchar(256)
, cap.cap_ayrc varchar(256)
, stu.stu_fnm1 varchar(256)
, stu.stu_surn varchar(256)
, cap.cap_stac varchar(256)
, cap.cap_crtd varchar(256)
);
/

create type t_tab is table of t_row;
/

create or replace function reject_list(ayrc varchar2, mcrc varchar2)
  return t_tab pipelined
begin
  for cur in
  (
  select distinct 
         cap.cap_uci2
         , cap.cap_stuc
         , cap.cap_mcrc
         , cap.cap_ayrc
         , stu.stu_fnm1
         , stu.stu_surn
         , cap.cap_stac
         , cap.cap_crtd
  from intuit.srs_cap cap
       , intuit.ins_stu stu
       , intuit.srs_apf apf
  where cap.cap_stuc = stu.stu_code
        and cap.cap_apfs = apf.apf_seqn
        and cap.cap_stuc = apf.apf_stuc
        and cap.cap_mcrc = mcrc
        and cap.cap_ayrc = ayrc
        and cap.cap_idrc in ('R', 'CR', 'CFR')
        and apf.apf_recd <= to_date ('1501' || substr(ayrc, 1, 4), 'DDMMYYYY')
  )
    loop
      pipe row(cur);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

After that you can use the function this way (change `'xxx'`, `'yyy'` on your param's values):

```
select *
from table(reject_list('xxx', 'yyy'));
```